# Xubuntu doesn't ask me to create a new user on first boot (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: xubuntu, vps

I've been trying for few days to install xubuntu which seems to works the best with rdp (less latency)
Here is how I proceed:

-Boot the vps

-use "tasksel" command

-select Xubuntu Desktop from the GUI

-reboot

-Connect with VNC

-and i'm stuck there at the login screen it doesn't let me create a new user...
login with root user don't work either as it's not enabled for the gui
[Login Screen, first boot after Xubuntu installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq9Ga.png)

Installed on vps with 4 cores 8 gb Ram 200GB SSD

Thanks in advance for your help guys.
PS: I'm new on Linux.
when I install Ubuntu desktop instead of Xubuntu Desktop it ask me to create new user but not with Xubuntu

Comment: I guess this is the only solution, sudo adduser i'll investigate it

Comment: This is not related to Xubuntu itself, but the question is about the config given by the VPS provider. When you install Xubuntu a normal way, you don't have to create a new user.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with `sudo adduser` command, that gui can't create a new user on first login because its weak so just do it manually.